# No imprime valor de variable pasada por parámetro en una función. C

Tags: c, funciones, punteros, paso-por-referencia

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en C y estoy intentando, usando una función (obligatoriamente), pedir un número por pantalla y dar ese valor introducido a mi variable, pero cuando ejecuto el main simplemente imprime el 0 de la última línea y no imprime el valor de mi variable. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias

```
#include <stdio.h>
void leerint(int *);
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int numeroa;
   leerint(&numeroa);
   printf("%d", numeroa);
   return 0;
}
void leerint(int *a){
   printf("Escribe un numero\n");
   scanf("%d", &a);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
void leerint(int *a){
  printf("Escribe un numero\n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
}
```

`a` **ya es un puntero**; tal y como lo estás usando `scanf( "%d", &a )` estas pasando un *puntero a puntero* (, en otras palabras, la *dirección de una dirección*), lo cual es perfectamente válido, pero no es lo que pretendes hacer.

Simplemente, quita la *indirección* al llamar a `scanf( )`:

```
void leerint(int *a){
  printf("Escribe un numero\n");
  scanf("%d", a);
}
```